# Floating nav excaping bounds on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav that scrolls with the window and stops above the footer, which is working really well. Except when you reload the page or navigate to it using the back button after scrolling down past where the `nav` should follow you.  then it shows up overlapping the footer until you scroll.  How can I get the `nav` to affix the `top:###px;` style to the `nav` when the page is first loaded?

**here is the existing code:**

```
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function ($) {
  function PageNavAffix(options) {
    this.$element = $('#page-nav');
    this.$container = $('#page-nav-container');
  }
  PageNavAffix.prototype.bindEvents = function () {
    $(window).on('resize', this.configureBounds.bind(this)) .trigger('resize');
    return this;
  };
  PageNavAffix.prototype.configureBounds = function () {
    var module = this;
    var vgapBase = 6;
    this.$element.affix({
      offset: {
        top: module.$container.offset().top + parseInt(module.$container.css('padding-top')) - vgapBase,
        bottom: function () {
                  var pageHeight = $('html').outerHeight();
                  var offset = module.$container.offset().top;
                  var containerOuterHeight = module.$container.outerHeight();
                  var containerPadding = parseInt(module.$container.css('padding-bottom'));
                  var containerHeight = containerOuterHeight - containerPadding;
                  this.bottom = pageHeight - offset - containerHeight;
                }
            }
        });
    };
    return PageNavAffix;
});
```

Comment: could use a working example here

Comment: http://gmpmulti.staging.wpengine.com/help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping on it, I've found a few solutions/workarounds.  I added this to the bindEvents function:

```
$(window)
  .on('beforeunload', function() {
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
  });
```

OR  I could add this instead:

```
$(window)
  .on('load', function() {
      $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-1);
  });
```

Comment: If someone has a cleaner solution I'll accept that instead of my own, but this solves the problem as far as the client is concerned.